# Does a CSS @import expose the users IP address?

Tags: css, http, request, css-import

When doing a `@import` from a external third party URL inside a CSS file, which data client data will be exposed to the third party?

I’m not quite sure if the third party will be able to see my visitors IP address which would be interesting in terms of GDPR.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not try and see? Whatever the browser requests is loaded through the browser, so it obvious that the external server logs a request coming from the browser

Comment: Yes the third party will see the IP. Also the User Agent, the referer and other stuff that is in the headers. You can check with your dev tools in the network tab. Try including google fonts... They also can set cookies and combine the referrers to create a profile.

Comment: Every `@import` is an additional HTTP GET Request so yeah. There's not much benefit to using `@import` other than keeping all the styles in .css files loading from there as well instead of <link /> tags.

Comment: Thank you, I thought of that but was not _really_ sure. I agree that testing this out was the proper way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

CSS is parsed client-side. An instruction to fetch additional CSS from another URL will have to be carried out client-side. The users' browsers will make HTTP requests to the URL.